# How to read all .txt files from a directory

Tags: python, arrays, string, readfile, listdir

I would like to read all the contents from all the text files in a directory. I have 4 text files in the "path" directory, and my codes are;

```
for filename in os.listdir(path):
    filepath = os.path.join(path, filename)
    with open(filepath, mode='r') as f:
        content = f.read()
        thelist = content.splitlines()
        f.close()
        print(filepath)
        print(content)
        print()
```

When I run the codes, I can only read the contents from **only one text file**.

I will be thankful that there are any advice or suggestions from you or that you know any other informative inquiries for this question in stackoverflow.

Comment: you are overwriting `thelist` on each iteration

Comment: Side note: no need for an explicit `f.close()` inside a `with open(...) as f:` block.

Comment: When you run it does the print statement print something for all four? or is it just only saving one of them

Comment: @Hippolippo it was saving one of them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to filter the files' name per suffix, i.e. file extension, you can either use the string method `endswith` or the `glob` module of the standard library https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html
Here an example of code which save each file content as a string in a list.

```
import os

path = '.' # or your path

files_content = []

for filename in filter(lambda p: p.endswith("txt"), os.listdir(path)):
    filepath = os.path.join(path, filename)
    with open(filepath, mode='r') as f:
        files_content += [f.read()]
```

With the `glob` way here an example

```
import glob

for filename in glob.glob('*txt'):
    print(filename)
```

Comment: thank you very much. it helped me understand which part was missing. thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, if you want to read all the files, you need to save them somehow. In your example, you are overriding `thelist` with `content.splitlines()` which deletes everything already in it.
Instead you should define `thelist` outside of the loop and use `thelist.append(content.splitlines)` each time, which adds the content to the list each iteration

Then you can iterate over `thelist` later and get the data out.

Answer (score 2):

This should list your file and you can read them one by one. All the lines of the files are stored in `all_lines` list. If you wish to store the content too, you can keep append it too

```
from pathlib import Path
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join

path = "path_to_dir"
only_files = [f for f in listdir(path) if isfile(join(path, f))]
all_lines = []
for file_name in only_files:
    file_path = Path(path) / file_name
    with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
        file_content = f.read()
        all_lines.append(file_content.splitlines())
        print(file_content)

# use all_lines
```

Note: when using `with` you do not need to call `close()` explicitly

Reference: [How do I list all files of a directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207219/how-do-i-list-all-files-of-a-directory)

Comment: i appreciate your help and suggestion. thank you so much :)